# Why does this piece of code say variable j might not have been initialized?? It is getting initialized inside the loop

Tags: java, for-loop, variables, initialization

```
class Searching{
        
    static int search(int arr[], int N, int X)
    {
        
        
       int j;
        
        for(int i =  0; i<N; i++){
            
            if(arr[i] == X){
                
          j = i;
           
            break;
                
            }
        }
        
       return j;
        
    }
    
}
```

I have initialized j inside the loop. So why does the compiler say j is not initialized when it reaches the return statement. I am not able to understand as I am new to coding.. Please help me

Comment: What if the loop is never executed? What do you return?

Comment: Simple answer, at compile time, compiler will not know whether for loop will execute or not. So you NEED to initialize your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `for` loops are pre-test loops: the test (`i<N`) is executed before the loop body. So if `N` is less than or equal to the initial value of `i` (`0`), then the loop wil never execute and `j` will never be initialised.

But there’s another issue that the commentators missed: even if the loop executes, if the element being searched for does not exist in the array, `j` will never be initialised.

---

On another note, instead of passing `N` as a parameter, you should be able to get it directly from the array (though I can’t remember how to do it right now).

Answer (score 1):

This is happens because the parameter `N` can be equals to 0, so the loop isn't must running, or array isn't contains `x`, so the variable `j` will not initialize.
I suggest you to initialize like `int j = -1;`, and than if the method returns `-1` you will know that something go wrong (`N = 0` or array isn't contains `x`).